# Bash pass the file names which are not in the ith element of loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

In a simple processing of files, where you want to do something on every file in a directory, you do something like this:

```
for i in file1 file2 file3 file5
do
echo "Processing $i"
done
```

What I want to do here is pass $i as well as the non-$i files as an argument to a command. Lets say my directory contains 4 files (file1, file2, file3, file5). For example in the first iteration of the loop when file1 is being processed, I want to pass the rest of the files (file2, file3, file5) to the -b argument of the command.

For example, **first iteration of loop** in bash should look something like this:

```
FILES=/path/to/directory
for i in $FILES
do
bedtools intersect -a $i -b file2 file3 file5
done
```

In **second iteration** as the file2 is in the $i the rest of the files will be passed to `-b` argument.

```
for i in $FILES
do
bedtools intersect -a $i -b file1 file3 file5
done
```

and so on for all the files in the directory. In short, pass the current file to `-a` argument and rest of the files to `-b` argument.

It will be great if somebody can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a numeric loop and take slices out of the array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( path/to/directory/* )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; ++i )); do
    file=${files[i]}
    others=( "${files[@]:0:i}" "${files[@]:i+1}" )
    bedtools intersect -a "$file" -b "${others[@]}"
done
```

This loops though the indices of the array `files` and slices the part before and after the current index `i` to get the `others`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think it is not passing the $other filenames correctly. I am getting an error for that. I have tried manually and it is working when I do it following way: `bedtools intersect -a file1.txt -b file2.txt file3.txt .. fileN.txt > output.txt`. Can you please add an echo line so that I can see what I am passing to these arguments? Thanks.

Comment: The $others file names should be separated by a space.

Comment: If you add `set -x` to the script, you will be able to see the commands that are being executed.

Comment: @Newbie "${others[@]}" expands to each element of the array as separate words (arguments).

Comment: I am using 1 extra thing may be that is causing problem. Can you please suggest me how can I do it right. To get the first index of my file by separating its filename on `_`: `a=$(echo $file | cut -d "_" -f 1)` and then saving the output as `bedtools intersect -a "$file" -b "${others[@]}" > $a `

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand what you're trying to do with the code in your comment but I'm glad you've got it working anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out like this as well,

```
op=$(find /path/to/directory ! -iname ".*")                                                      
temp=$op                                                                        

for i in $op;                                                                   
do                                                                              
    rfile=${temp//$i/}                                                          
    rfile=$(echo $rfile | tr '\n' ' ')                                          
    bedtools intersect -a $i -b $rfile                                              
done
```

Comment: This is wrong. Files with any kind of whitespace will break your code horribly!

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0; files=(*)
for i in ${files[*]}; do 
   unset files[count]
   echo "bedtools intersect -a $i -b ${files[*]}"
   files+=($i)
   ((count++))
done
```

Comment: Things seriously wrong with your code: 1) Filenames with whitespace characters will break your code. 2) You are not using the perks of arrays, use `"${files[@]}"` instead! 3) Quote expansions: `files+=("$i")`. 4) Quote the `unset` command otherwise it is a subject to pathname expansion. Should your directory have a file called `fileso`, it would break your code. Also, note that you could loop over indexes of the array. There would be no need for `count` then.